# how to clear() integer in c++

Tags: c++

I try to fill two-dimension array with words. i have 'sliced' the temporary string into single chars stored in temporary one dimension array. at he end of main 'for' loop i want to reset all temporary variables. The problem is that i cannot clear integer. Any ideas how to proceed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
for(int j=0; j!=4; j++)
{
    if (j==0)
    cout << "text1: \n";
    else if(j==1)
    cout << "text2: \n";
    else if(j==2)
    cout << "text3: ?\n";
    else if(j==3)
    cout << "text4: \n";
    string temp; getline(cin, temp);
    int lenght = temp.size();
    char test[lenght+1];
    strcpy(test, temp.c_str());
    char tab[4][lenght];
    for(int i=0; i!=lenght+1; i++)
    {
        tab[j][i]=test[i];
    }
    temp.clear();
    lenght.clear();   //error
    test.clear();
}
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error

```
/root/Dokumenty/fgfg/main.cpp|26|error: request for member ‘clear’ in ‘lenght’, which is of non-class type ‘int’|
```

Comment: `length` is of type `int`. Why do you want to call `clear()`?

Comment: to clear stream or buffer i don't know. i'm begginer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to reset all temporary variables

Why? This requirement appears to be entirely arbitrary.

Furthermore, it makes no sense, because C++ already does this for you: those variables are bound to the scope of the loop. Each time the loop iterates, you get new versions of the variables. The integers of one iteration are unrelated to the integers of the last iteration.

Of course to "clear" an integer in general you'd just set it to whatever you initialised it to, e.g. `0`.

By the way, that is not how we spell "length".

Answer (score 0):

the `.clear` only works for strings